# Black screen video (mobile devieces)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, video

Video does not work on android chrome ( tested in 38-40 version ), i have black screen in chrome and opera in firefox all works, and i have same problem on ios safari.

```
var v = document.createElement(  "video"  );
v.type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';
v.src = "http://cyberua.16mb.com/player/data/video3.mp4";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0du7LmfL/3/embedded/result/

[**Update**]
I finded fix, but why dont work with document.create?

```
 var video = '<video id="really-cool-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls ' +
        ' preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="really-cool-video-poster.jpg" data-setup="{}"> <source src="http://cyberua.16mb.com/player/data/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4">  </video>'
 document.body.innerHTML = video;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0du7LmfL/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in video encoding

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

- :  VP8 and Vorbis in WebM
- :  H.264 and MP3 in MP4
- : H.264 and AAC in MP4